# Add missing rows per group to fill a series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following df:

| Name | Time Elapsed | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | $2 |
| A | 5 | $1 |
| A | 7 | $6 |
| B | 3 | $3 |
| B | 5 | $5 |

I would like to expand this per group so that I get all the times in between the min and max, and then fill downwards (assuming it's sorted by name then by time elapsed) to produce the following output

| Name | Time Elapsed | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | $2 |
| A | 3 | $2 |
| A | 4 | $2 |
| A | 5 | $1 |
| A | 6 | $1 |
| A | 7 | $6 |
| B | 3 | $3 |
| B | 4 | $3 |
| B | 5 | $5 |

I tried the following:

```
df = df(df.set_index('Time Elapsed')
          .groupby('Name')['Amount']
          .apply(lambda x: x.reindex(range(x.index.min(), x.index.max()+1))
          .ffill().fillna(0)).reset_index)
```

Feel free to offer a solution that does not use any of my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
def func(g: pd.DataFrame):
    tmp = g.set_index('Time Elapsed')
    res = tmp.reindex(
        np.arange(tmp.index.min(), tmp.index.max()+1),
        method='ffill')
    return res

grouped = df.groupby('Name', as_index=False)
result = grouped.apply(func).reset_index().reindex(columns=df.columns)
print(result)
>>>
Name    Time   Elapsed   Amount
0       A      2         $2
1       A      3         $2
2       A      4         $2
3       A      5         $1
4       A      6         $1
5       A      7         $6
6       B      3         $3
7       B      4         $3
8       B      5         $5
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is with [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), to expose the missing rows:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

# build a dictionary of all the possible times
# the key of the dictionary should be the column to be expanded
times = {"Time Elapsed" : lambda df: range(df.min(), df.max() + 1)}
df.complete(times, by = 'Name').ffill()
  Name  Time Elapsed Amount
0    A             2     $2
1    A             3     $2
2    A             4     $2
3    A             5     $1
4    A             6     $1
5    A             7     $6
6    B             3     $3
7    B             4     $3
8    B             5     $5
```